# Match Function Multiple Criteria with inequality (excel function)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns of data:

- A has names in rows 1-5 (Amy, Greg, Matt, Sean, Greg).
- B has numbers in rows 1-5 (90, 20, 30, 40, 50).

I want to write an excel function that will give me the number of the row with the name Greg in column A where the number in column B is greater than 25.

I have tried two functions that are not working:

```
=MATCH("Greg"&TRUE,A1:A6&B1:B6>25,0)

=Match("Greg"&>25,A1:A6&B1:B6,0)
```

I am pressing ctrl + shift + enter to do an array and it is still not working.

I am unable to sort the values (due to other constraints) so I cannot use the final argument in the match function to achieve the `>25` argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a standard formula AGGREGATE instead of an array formula MATCH.

```
=aggregate(15, 7, row(a:a)/((a$1:a$6="greg")*(b$1:b$6>25)), 1)
```

To get possible second, third, etc. matching row numbers, change the 1 at the end to row(1:1) and fill down.

While I don't typically use this style of array formula, your original would have worked as a CSE formula if changed to this,

```
=MATCH("Greg"&TRUE, A1:A6&(B1:B6>25), 0)
```